# Multiple animations for 1 element JS, CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to animate Quicksort for my tutoring website i'm making. I'm using Keyframes animations with event listeners to fire the animations for each element back to back. The problem is that my object2 won't stay in the end position after it's second animation. It performs it's first animation for no reason when I have not added a third animation on it when I call an animation on a totally different element.

The problem occurs with function 7 when I animate object 8.

The problem is that object 2 won't stay in the position that it ended in after it's second animation. When I animate object 8, the last animation so far... object2 performs it's first animation even though I don't tell it to do anything and just want it to stay where it is.

```js
object1 = document.getElementById("object1");
object2 = document.getElementById("object2");
object3 = document.getElementById("object3");
object4 = document.getElementById("object4");
object5 = document.getElementById("object5");
object6 = document.getElementById("object6");
object7 = document.getElementById("object7");
object8 = document.getElementById("object8");
object9 = document.getElementById("object9");
object10 = document.getElementById("object10");

function function1() {
  object5.style.animation = "animation1 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function2);
}

function function2() {
  object2.style.animation = "animation2 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function3);
}

function function3() {
  object5.style.animation = "animation3 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function4);
}

function function4() {

  object10.style.animation = "animation4 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object10.addEventListener("animationend", function5);
}

function function5() {
  object2.style.animation = "animation5 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function6);
}

function function6() {
  object5.style.animation = "animation6 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function7);
}

function function7() {
  object8.style.animation = "animation7 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object8.addEventListener("animationend", function8);
}

function function8() {
  object5.style.animation = "animation8 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function9);
}

function function9() {
  object4.style.animation = "animation9 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";

}
```

```css
#object1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

#object2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

#object3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

#object4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: purple;
  float: left;
}

#object5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}

#object6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: brown;
  float: left;
}

#object7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
}

#object8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: tomato;
  float: left;
}

#object9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: indigo;
  float: left;
}

#object10 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: mediumspringgreen;
  float: left;
}

#vacuum {
  height: 200px;
}

#vacuum2 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 65px;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(250px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(-400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-400px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(250px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(150px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation7 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation8 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-200px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-100px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation9 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation10 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(-250px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-250px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation11 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(250px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(250px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="vacuum"></div>
<div id="vacuum2"></div>
<div id="object1"></div>
<div id="object2"></div>
<div id="object3"></div>
<div id="object4"></div>
<div id="object5"></div>
<div id="object6"></div>
<div id="object7"></div>
<div id="object8"></div>
<div id="object9"></div>
<div id="object10"></div>
<button onclick="function1()">Click Mom :)</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Issue

The issue is caused by multiple eventListener's being attached to the same object. Specifically:

- `function2` starts an animation on `object2` and attaches an `animationend` listener to `object2`
- `function5` starts an animation on `object2` and attaches an `animationend` listener to `object2` (the 2nd event listener on `object2`)
- when the animation in `function5()` completes the event listeners from `function2` and `function5` are both called
- the callback functions from the event listeners in `function2` and `function5` cause new `animationend` events to trigger, causing `function3` and `function6` to be called.
- this causes a multiple animation sequences to start, which then multiply

I've added some `console.log`s to the demo below to help visualize this.

```js
object1 = document.getElementById("object1");
object2 = document.getElementById("object2");
object3 = document.getElementById("object3");
object4 = document.getElementById("object4");
object5 = document.getElementById("object5");
object6 = document.getElementById("object6");
object7 = document.getElementById("object7");
object8 = document.getElementById("object8");
object9 = document.getElementById("object9");
object10 = document.getElementById("object10");

function function1() {
  console.log('animation 1 - start')
  object5.style.animation = "animation1 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 1 - end')
    function2()
  });
}

function function2() {
  console.log('animation 2 - start')
  object2.style.animation = "animation2 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 2 - end')
    function3()
  });
}

function function3() {
  console.log('animation 3 - start')
  object5.style.animation = "animation3 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 3 - end')
    function4()
  });
}

function function4() {
  console.log('animation 4 - start')
  object10.style.animation = "animation4 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object10.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 4 - end')
    function5()
  });
}

function function5() {
  console.log('animation 5 - start')
  object2.style.animation = "animation5 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 5 - end')
    function6()
  });
}

function function6() {
  console.log('animation 6 - start')
  object5.style.animation = "animation6 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 6 - end')
    function7()
  });
}

function function7() {
  console.log('animation 7 - start')
  object8.style.animation = "animation7 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object8.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 7 - end')
    function8()
  });
}

function function8() {
  console.log('animation 8 - start')
  object5.style.animation = "animation8 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    console.log('animation 8 - end')
    function9()
  });
}

function function9() {
  object4.style.animation = "animation9 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";

}
```

```css
#object1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

#object2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

#object3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

#object4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: purple;
  float: left;
}

#object5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}

#object6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: brown;
  float: left;
}

#object7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
}

#object8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: tomato;
  float: left;
}

#object9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: indigo;
  float: left;
}

#object10 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: mediumspringgreen;
  float: left;
}

#vacuum {
  height: 200px;
}

#vacuum2 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 65px;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(250px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(-400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-400px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(250px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(150px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation7 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation8 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-200px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-100px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation9 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation10 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(-250px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-250px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation11 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(250px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(250px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="vacuum"></div>
<div id="vacuum2"></div>
<div id="object1"></div>
<div id="object2"></div>
<div id="object3"></div>
<div id="object4"></div>
<div id="object5"></div>
<div id="object6"></div>
<div id="object7"></div>
<div id="object8"></div>
<div id="object9"></div>
<div id="object10"></div>
<button onclick="function1()">Click Mom :)</button>
```

### The Solution

The solution is to `removeEventListener`s from the objects to prevent the previous functions from being called when later `animationend` events occur.

For example, to remove the `function2` event listener from `object5`:

```
function function2() {
  object5.removeEventListener('animationend', function2);
  object2.style.animation = "animation2 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function3);
}
```

Or, if you want to be more general, you can use the `event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee)` format, like:

```
function function2(event) {
  event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
  object2.style.animation = "animation2 2s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function3);
}
```

Here's the working solution:

```js
object1 = document.getElementById("object1");
object2 = document.getElementById("object2");
object3 = document.getElementById("object3");
object4 = document.getElementById("object4");
object5 = document.getElementById("object5");
object6 = document.getElementById("object6");
object7 = document.getElementById("object7");
object8 = document.getElementById("object8");
object9 = document.getElementById("object9");
object10 = document.getElementById("object10");

function function1() {
  object5.style.animation = "animation1 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function2);
}

function function2(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object2.style.animation = "animation2 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function3);
}

function function3(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object5.style.animation = "animation3 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function4);
}

function function4(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object10.style.animation = "animation4 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object10.addEventListener("animationend", function5);
}

function function5(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object2.style.animation = "animation5 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object2.addEventListener("animationend", function6);
}

function function6(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object5.style.animation = "animation6 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function7);
}

function function7(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object8.style.animation = "animation7 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object8.addEventListener("animationend", function8);
}

function function8(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object5.style.animation = "animation8 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";
  object5.addEventListener("animationend", function9);
}

function function9(e) {
  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
  object4.style.animation = "animation9 2s ease 1 normal running 0s forwards";

}
```

```css
#object1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

#object2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

#object3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

#object4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: purple;
  float: left;
}

#object5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}

#object6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: brown;
  float: left;
}

#object7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: pink;
  float: left;
}

#object8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: tomato;
  float: left;
}

#object9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: indigo;
  float: left;
}

#object10 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: mediumspringgreen;
  float: left;
}

#vacuum {
  height: 200px;
}

#vacuum2 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 65px;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(250px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(-400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-400px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(400px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(250px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(150px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation7 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation8 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-200px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-70px) translateX(-100px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation9 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation10 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(-250px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-250px);
  }
}

@keyframes animation11 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(70px) translateX(250px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) translateX(250px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="vacuum"></div>
<div id="vacuum2"></div>
<div id="object1"></div>
<div id="object2"></div>
<div id="object3"></div>
<div id="object4"></div>
<div id="object5"></div>
<div id="object6"></div>
<div id="object7"></div>
<div id="object8"></div>
<div id="object9"></div>
<div id="object10"></div>
<button onclick="function1()">Click Mom :)</button>
```